# Mozilla nonsense. Page changes size by itself

Tags: firefox

I have never intentionally changed the size of font on latest mozilla browser install on windows machine.  For example Google site is now 200% size, and I did nothing to make this happen. Whats worse is it does not change back but remembers this!  Similarly other sites are too small and they remember this per site. What is going on here? I mean what nonsense!  How can I undo this? And for extra points who came up with this absurd behavior at mozilla? Not making this up folks. 15.0.1  Not at all clear why it changes size or how to go back to default size for these sites

Acutally it just happened again while editing this entry. Icon changes and than font size is too small.

Comment: Ctrl + 0(zero) resets zoom level to 100%

Comment: It's possible that a `Ctrl` button is stuck or faulty on your keyboard, based on the way you describe it.

Comment: ok. thanks that worked. Any idea what I did to make the size change?

Comment: Ctrl + scroll(middle mouse button) can do that

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `Ctrl` key was stuck while you scrolled over the page. `Ctrl+0` resets to default size.

You can disable this feature in Firefox like this: enter `about:config` in URL bar (you will see an warning ), search for `mousewheel.withcontrolkey.action` and change it from `3` to `0` this will disable the re-sizing.